# IIS + Apache tomcat in same machine

Tags: iis-6, tomcat5.5

Can IIS server (Port 80) and Apache Tomcat (Port 8080) function in the same machine properly without any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are bound to different ports (80 for IIS and 8080 for tomcat) as you state, that will work.